# Morris.js missing label writing per one

Tags: javascript

and thanks in advance.
i have this problem that in the plugin when i bring information with an ajax for building a bar chart with  "Morris.js" ,every second bar of the axis is not showing the information , but if i write the "json" straight to the code it works fine what is my mistake?  here is the code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 

 var numberOfSeconds=30*1000; //the interval of refreshing the information of the calls per server
 var x=getTheInfoAboutTheServers();



//The m_graph contains an information 
   //and build the graph itself later we update the data with the m_graph.setData() function
     var m_graph= Morris.Bar({
            element: 'my_chart',
            data:   x,
            xkey: 'y',
            ykeys: ['a'],
            labels: ['Number of calls']
        });

/**
 * This Function get the number of calls per each server
 * return a JSON object to the morris.js pluggin
 */

function getTheInfoAboutTheServers(){

var inf=null;

$.ajax({

     async: false,    
     type: "POST",
     url : $('#site_url').val()+"index.php/Login_controller/mw_iaa_rawGraphInfoClient",
     dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data){


            var dataArr=[];

                for (key in data) {
                    if (!isNaN(key)) {
                        var obj = data[key];

                        var mySplitResult = obj['callserver'].split(".");
                        var calls=parseInt(obj['numOfCalls']);


                        dataArr.push({ y: String(mySplitResult[0]), a : calls});
                      }
                  }
            inf=dataArr;

       }
 });    

 return inf;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because $.ajax executes asynchronously in the function getTheInfoAboutTheServers. Accordingly, this method returns the value of inf,ie, *null* as the ajax function isn't executed at that moment.

To solve this issue, you need to call another function from within the ajax-success method passing on the json as a parameter instead assigning it to a variable

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,but it do return a json and i see the graph

Comment: i also see everything right in the tooltips , but in the axis every second column misses its name